# Database design with learners assigned to time slots and testing machines

Tags: mysql, database

I am having a dilemma approaching how to to design my database to produce what I need.

I am trying to create a simple time slot booking system that has preset times a learner can be booked onto. Within that the person needs to be allocated to a laptop that they must sit their test on.

To visualise it would look something like this:

```
****************************************************************
* Machine/Laptop *   Time Slot   *      Name      *     Test   *
****************************************************************
*                * 09:00 - 12:00 * John Adams     * English    *
*    Laptop 1    * 12:00 - 14:00 * Amy Smith      * Maths      *
*                * 14:00 - 16:00 * Raj Patel      * English    *
****************************************************************
*                * 09:00 - 12:00 * Joe King       * English    *
*    Laptop 2    * 12:00 - 14:00 * Andrew Lil     * Maths      *
*                * 14:00 - 16:00 * FREE           * English    *
****************************************************************
```

Carrying on up to 10 laptops.

I know how to create basic databases from my understanding the basic structure would include having three db tables:

- Learner - Stores all the learner information
- Testing - Stores the testing event e.g. day, location etc.
- Machines - Stores the laptop names and time slot per row so I would have three rows that matched laptop 1 with different times

What I don't know is my approach to make Testing and Machines work together. Any advice on how to approach would be great, unless im looking at this wrong and any other way to approach it would also be great!

Comment: Machines should only store info about the particular laptop, not the time slot info. Add a table to store the time slot assigned to a learner with foreign keys to learners, machines and the test. It would also contain the time slot info, or if the time slots are consistent (ie.there is a list of time slots), a link to another table with time slots.